# Notepad++ explicit quantifier notation

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've been playing around with the Notepad++ regular expression engine, but there's something I can't make work, it's the explicit quantifier notation.

I've seen some other posts here where the following syntax is used : (expr){1,2}

However, when I use it in a test as simple as `k{1,1}`
where the text to search is k : there is no match. 
I tried a lot of syntax's : {1,}, {1}, etc.
Am I missing something here ?

Please excuse my bad english, and thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Starting with version 6.0, Notepad++ supports PCRE ([source](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html)). Quantifiers will work as expected in these versions.

The regex engine of Notepad++ 5.9.8 and lower does **not** support quantifiers ([source](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3234792&group_id=95717&atid=612382)).

You can, however, use the following quantifiers:

- `k*`, which is equivalent to `k{0,}`.
- `k+`, which is equivalent to `k{1,}`.
- `k?`, which is equivalent to `k{0,1}`.

If you want other quantifiers, you can combine the above methods.

Examples:

- `kkk+` emulates `k{3,}`
- `kkkk?k?` emulates `k{3,5}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! disappointing, as it makes me build loooong expressions, but at least now I know for sure :)

Comment: Notepad++ is based on [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html), which uses old school POSIX regexes and these quantifiers didn't work there.

Comment: @Dennis Never mind, I confused myself with a complex regex I was working on.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++'s regular expression system does not appear to support that feature. They do support `k+` and `k*`.