# How to select all similar codes in Notepad++ with Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have bunch of "id" codes in text - I would like to select them all and delete:

```
... id="S60K141" ... id="Z80Y144" ... id="V60O175" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `CTRL + H` to open replace box, turn on regex, and replace with empty string.

```
id=".*?"
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of `.*?` as this will result in backtracking. You could just write `id="[^"]+"` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `id="[A-Z0-9]{7}"` with nothing.

Autopsy:

- `id="` - the literal character sequence `id="`
- `[A-Z0-9]{7}` - letters from `A` to `Z` and digits from `0` to `9` repeated exactly 7 times
- `"` - the literal character `"`

Comment: if part of codes have different number of characters between quotes than what should I put instead of {7}?

Comment: @Robert002 `+` means "repeated 1 or more times" (`id="[A-Z0-9]+"`). You can use that. If it has to have at least 7 characters, you can use `{7,}`. If it has to have between 7 and 10 characters, you can use `{7,10}` etc.

Comment: @NullUserException I hate to ask a 39K user this question, but you *have* remembered to check the "Regular expression" box in "Search mode", right? I use NPP 6.5, btw.

Comment: Yeah, I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/9Qv4W54.png) with NPP 5.9.4 on Windows. The regex should work, but it looks like quantifiers `{n}` and `{n,m}` are not working here. If I replace `{7}` with `+` then it works fine, but obviously they don't mean the same thing.

Comment: @NullUserException [PCRE expressions were added in 6.0](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.0.html), though `{n,m}` shouldn't be limited to PCRE? They probably had a buggy regex engine. [Wikipedia *does* mention that *This is not found in a few older instances of regular expressions.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and just [one more source from SO regarding this exact problem in NPP 5.9-](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924286/notepad-explicit-quantifier-notation/7924380#7924380).

Comment: Well, that explains it. Notepad++ is based on [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html), which uses old school POSIX regexes and these quantifiers didn't work there. PCRE is certainly a welcome addition.

Comment: @今草顿웃 You realize that `.*?` is lazy right? Greedy would screw the whole thing up.