# Regex, replacing for newline with group replace

Tags: regex

```
675185538end432 204 9/9 4709 908 2
343269172end430 3 43 9335 975 7
590144128end89 7 29 3-5-4 420 2
337460105end8Y5 7A 78 2 23
292484648end70 A53 03 9235 93
```

These are the strings that I am working with. I want to find a regex to replace the above strings as follows

```
675185538
432 204 9/9 4709 908 2
343269172
430 3 43 9335 975 7
590144128
89 7 29 3-5-4 420 2
337460105
8Y5 7A 78 2 23
292484648
70 A53 03 9235 93
```

Wherever `end` comes, `\r\n` should be introduced.
The string before `end` is numeric and after `end` is alphanumeric with whiteline characters.
I am using notepad++.

Comment: Why do you think you need regex? Have you tried just replacing `end` with `\r\n`?

Comment: The thing is there are more than just this string alone.there are string before and after these numbers. thats why i need a regex to match this string and replace.

Comment: and the end is not only in this place but also in many other places. So only regex can search match the string and then replace

Comment: Ok, it seemed you had only the text which you posted. So what have you tried already? From the terms you used ("groups", "numeric", "alphanumeric") it seems you know already how to do it.

Comment: I used
Find: ^(\d+)end(\d)
Replace: \1\r\n\2
&
Find (\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)end(\d)

Replace \1\r\n\2

a little modification was needed when i executed, but both are brilliant regex. Thanks to both of them, i marked one as answer as it was simple, and other as useful, it was brilliant

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kludgery:

Find `(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)end(\d)`

Replace `\1\r\n\2`

Find creates two capture groups:

- each group is bounded by an `(` and a `)`
- one capture group matches exactly nine numerals
- the other capture group matches exactly one numeral.

In the replace:

- the first capture group is referenced with `\1`
- and the second group with `\2`.

Comment: In keeping with the purpose of my answer, I composed the Regex for clarity of communication. The problem when trying to understand Regex's is not the concepts but the poor syntax dating back more than 40 years. Sure, in those days saving keystrokes made sense - just like assembly language.

Comment: The problem is not the repetition of \d but the limitation for the number. With this we have to update the regex for each kind of number we want.

Comment: @benrudgers: What's wrong with regex syntax, how would you do it better? Btw, saving keystrokes is still relevant, and in your example using a repetition operator would make the expression much more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_Repeat_Yourself) and maintainable.

Comment: @GarciaJulien: The Regex is based on the problem's description and limiting it to exactly that domain is a feature. It would be an assumption on our part that the Regex should match on strings of digits preceding "end" of arbitrary length. In addition, versions of Notepad++ prior to 6, do not support `{n}` notation. See this SO topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924286/notepad-explicit-quantifier-notation.

Comment: @Bergi : Stealing from the Preface to the first edition of SICP - The problem with the standard Regex notation is that it is designed for computers to implement, rather than for humans to read. Sure, people can come to learn the Regex language if they use it all the time. But just switching between programming languages or even code editors often means reading the documentation to figure out why a perfectly good Perl regex fails in eLisp...or why `\d{9}end\d` doesn't work in the old version of Notepad++ which is old because it is so rarely used.

Answer (score 3):

To make the match strict, try this:

```
Find: ^(\d+)end(\w)
Replace: \1\r\n\2
```

This captures, then puts back via back references, the preceding number between start of line and "end" and the following digit/letter. This won't match "end" elsewhere.

Comment: what if we are not sureif its digits or letter?
^(\d+)end(\d) is there anything we can add to (\d) so it will say either number or digit? anyhow, your regex is cool :)

Comment: Thanks :) OK, I've made it match letter or digit after "end". Try it now.